# Lagrange multiplier failure, need help to maximize.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Lagrange multipliers are basically used to find the maximum and minimum points (or critical points) of a function given that a constraint function is defined. I have been trying all sorts of ways to solve the following problem and I just could not find a way to determine critical points. The question is:

**Constraint function** $$x+y+\arccos(-\cos(x+y))=\pi$$

**Function** $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(x+y)$$

As you can see, since these are trigonometric function - there partial derivatives $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$ are same which becomes an issue because then lambda (multiplier) in both cases are exactly the same.

One other thing to note is that $x$ and $y$ are angles and their ranges go from $0$ to $\pi/2$. There definitely exists a maximum because the function above represents an area of a triangle inscribed in a circle and from my own experimentation I believe that the maximum area (or function) can go near 0.5.

If you feel that this question has been asked before, please give me a link to the question and if any further information needs to be provided please let me know. Thank you in advance.

EDIT

I have found the solution I was looking for but I am still open to other derivations of solutions. If anyone wants to see how I found the answer feel free to ask and I will post it in here.

Comment: Note that the constraint function is satisfied when $0\le x+y\le\pi$. Lagrange Multipliers often fail when a constraint doesn't really constrain. In this case, just let $x+y=\frac\pi2$ to maximize $\frac12\sin(x+y)$.